# Defragging SSD once in order to shrink partition is also bad?

Tags: ssd, defragment

I need to somehow "defrag" my windows 7 partition in order to make a smaller image-backup of it, But windows disk management won't allow me to shrink the partition beyond x mb I need. Defraggler shows some movable files in the middle of my SSD. But I remembered defragging is never needed for ssd because of wear-leveling and zero seek etcetera. I get that. But is once that bad? Then i remembered some more intriguing technical bro-scares all over the web saying something "SSD internal disk software mapping files not 1:1 logical to OS file mapping and defraggers do not zero SSD cells and sorth"This could kill your disk do harm blah bla. So now I do not know what to do. Defrag once or never ever at all becaue of point two like the internet says. What is the truth to all the statements.

I need real expert advice not bro comments.
Please help.

Comment: Smart partition imaging tools will only read those partition sectors that actually contain data. No partition shrinking or defragging is required.

Comment: What software are you using to backup your windows?

Comment: GUI partitioners nowadays (such as partition wizard or EaseUS Partition Master...) automatically move files at the end of the disk so you don't need to defrag. They can also shrink the disk to a size much smaller than the amount windows diskmgmt.msc can do, and they are free. Of course you can buy other tools such as acronis disk director

Answer (score 2):

Each sector on the SSD has a certain number of write cycles (some says it is a 1000, but I think it has improved since then) it will take to fail.  However, SSD are usually pack with 1000's of spare sectors to automatically compensate for this situation.  Running defrag once in a while will not cause the universe to implode.  It is not recommend to do it on a regular basis, maybe once or twice a year.

```
Get gparted or partedmagic make a bootable CD from the ISO.
Boot from it and shrink/move or whatever the partitions.
Launch the **partition editor**
The software will automatically move the files out of the way automatically.
```

As @gronostaj mentioned smart (most modern) imaging tools only image your files and not the free space.  If reducing the partition size actually decrease the image size by more than a few MB your using poorly written/configured software.